# ¿Cómo obtener el número de divs dentro de su elemento padre?

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo la siguiente estructura en mi DOM:

```
 <body>
   <div></div>
  <ul>
    <li><div></div><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Lo que quiero realizar usando Vanilla Javascript es obtener el número de divs que se encuentran dentro de cada elemento padre incluyendo el tag `body`, sé que es utilizando una función recursiva lo cual aún no entiendo muy bien su uso.

Mi código JS hasta el momento es:

```
var getParents = function() {
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                return elems[i];
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

¡Saludos!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que mencionas en [un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16578/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-el-n%C3%BAmero-de-divs-dentro-de-su-elemento-padre#comment27205_16583), que lo que quieres es agregar la cuenta en un atributo `data-`, aquí te dejo una posibilidad. Consiste en hacer lo siguiente:

- Crea una lista con el `body` y todos sus descendientes (usando `querySelectorAll`).
- Para cada elemento de la lista:

  - Crea un `data-` atributo llamado `data-num-divs` (con `setAttribute) y
  - Asígnale como valor el número de `div` que descienden de él (usando `querySelectorAll`)

Para seleccionar todos los  `div` de esa rama deberías hacer algo como `querySelectorAll("div")`, en cambio, si sólo quieres contar los `div` que descienden directamente de ese elemento (sólo los hijos), entonces el selector sería `querySelectoAll(":scope > div")`.

Éste es el código comentado, inspecciona los elementos para ver los resultados:

```js
// seleciona una lista de elementos con el body y todos sus descendientes
var todos = document.querySelectorAll("body, body *");

// para cada elemento en la lista 
todos.forEach(function(elemento, indice, arreglo) {
  // crea un atributo data-num-divs y asigna el número de divs descendientes
  elemento.setAttribute("data-num-divs", elemento.querySelectorAll("div").length);
  
  // crea un atributo data-num-divs-hijos y asigna el número de divs descendientes directos
  elemento.setAttribute("data-num-divs-hijos", elemento.querySelectorAll(":scope > div").length);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <ul>
    <li><div></div><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sublime, es justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

## Intentalo

```js
// Selector Padre
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

// Cantidad de div
var divs = parent.querySelectorAll('div');
var cantidad = divs.length;

//Mostrar
//console.log('Cantidad de DIVS: '+cantidad);
document.write('Cantidad de DIVS: '+cantidad);
```

```html
 <body id="parent">
   <div></div>
  <ul>
    <li><div></div><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

si quieres obtener la cantidad total de divs en tu html, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var divList = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var total = divList.length;
alert("divs en total: "+total);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo que sucede es que necesito forzosamente los elementos padre y contar los divs de cada uno de los mismos ya que posteriormente agregaré un data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

El truco esta en usa propiedad [children](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

Un ejemplos del uso listando los div del cual depende el `<body>`

```js
var getParents = function() 
{
    var items = new Array();
  
    var elems = document.body.children;
  
    for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) 
    {
       if(elems[i].tagName == 'DIV')
           items.push(elems[i]);
    }
  
    return items;
}


var divs = getParents();

// se listan los elementos
for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  alert(divs[i].tagName);
}

//conocer el nro de elementos
alert("Nro DIV: " + divs.length);
```

```html
 <body>
   <div></div>
  <ul>
    <li><div></div><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```